# How to avoid the data loss when apply s3 in loki?

Tags: amazon-s3, grafana-loki

I am using s3 for loki storage

```
[root@localhost workspace]# s3cmd --recursive ls s3://test-bucket
2023-08-17 00:11          892  s3://test-bucket/fake/a034750b6666fb5a:18a00d202a7:18a00d20b73:3abe898d
2023-08-17 00:25         3517  s3://test-bucket/fake/a034750b6666fb5a:18a00dc39e6:18a00deec98:e5bd7490
2023-08-17 00:49         1444  s3://test-bucket/fake/a034750b6666fb5a:18a00f39a94:18a00f4cf4c:7eaab74
2023-08-17 01:20          718  s3://test-bucket/fake/a034750b6666fb5a:18a0111e27b:18a0111ea4d:17bd05d0
2023-08-17 00:17          608  s3://test-bucket/index/index_19586/loki-0-1692230744453156865-1692231074.gz
2023-08-17 00:32          610  s3://test-bucket/index/index_19586/loki-0-1692231435631236291-1692231915.gz
2023-08-17 01:02          610  s3://test-bucket/index/index_19586/loki-0-1692232872971746700-1692233352.gz
2023-08-17 00:06          251  s3://test-bucket/loki_cluster_seed.json
```

the loki's index was synced into s3 at `00:17`, `00:32`, `01:02`

for my test, some part data would be lost when i deleted the loki pod during `00:32 ~ 01:02`(e.g. 00:50)

How can i avoid the `data lost`?